# PostgreSQL query with IF ELSE in WHERE

Tags: sql, postgresql, if-statement

I have this query:

```
SELECT "visits".*
FROM "visits"
where   
    '2015-06-20' between start_date and end_date
or
    if (end_date is null) then end_date = '9999-01-01'
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.

The question is:

How to test if a date is in a range also without end_date in some rows?

`IF ELSE THEN` doesn't work in Postgres also if I use 1=1 or similar...

How to write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
select *
from visits
where date '2015-06-20' between start_date and coalesce(end_date, date '9999-01-01');
```

Or to make the "end" more obvious you can use `infinity`:

```
select *
from visits
where date '2015-06-20' between start_date and coalesce(end_date, 'infinity');
```

Comment: It workas, thanks, but if I want to use "IF", can you help me? Why it throw me an error on `then`?

Comment: IF doesn't exist in SQL, use CASE: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE

Comment: Oh, wow! And why this page? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html

Comment: @JohnSam That is the documentation of the syntax for the _procedural_ language PL/pgSQL which is used to write stored functions. That is **not** the documentation for SQL. There is no `IF` in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

use COALESCE and OVERLAPS.

```
SELECT v.*
FROM visits
WHERE (start_date,COALESCE(end_date, '9999-01-01'::date)) OVERLAPS ('2015-06-20'::date,'2015-06-20'::date)
```

Comment: It workas, thanks, but if I want to use "IF", can you help me? Why it throw me an error on `then`?